# Join fails to join whole files

Tags: bash, join

I am trying to use join to add a column onto a file with about 4.5M lines.  The files are sorted by their first column.  All the numbers in the first column in file 1 are in the first column in file 2.   when I use "join FILE1 FILE2 > output" it works for the first 1000 lines or so and then stops...

I am not married to the idea of join (program never seems to work right) and open to other ways to join these files. I tried grep, but doing this by grep for 4*10^6 records is very slow.  Below is a sample of the data I'm working with.

```
FILE 1
964 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -
965 0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -
966 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -
967 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 -
968 0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -
969 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 -
970 0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 -
971 0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -
1075 3 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -
1076 0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -
1077 0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 -
1078 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 -


File 2
964 T
965 C
966 T
967 G
968 C
969 T
970 G
971 C
972 G
973 G
974 T
975 G
976 C
977 T
978 G
979 G
980 C
981 T
982 G

output (Last few lines)
965 0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 - C
966 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 - T
967 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 - G
968 0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 - C
969 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 - T
970 0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 - G
971 0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 - C
9990 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 - T
9991 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 - C
```

EDIT 
Sorting in dictionary format works for all records after 463835.  I think it is because it sorted the input files differently, likely due to the other columns???

```
FILE 1 
466630 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -
46663 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 -
466631 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -

FILE 2
466639 C
46663 A
466640 G
```

Comment: 4.5 million lines that need to be joined: time to use a database; that's what they were invented for. (Now I'm curious as to how join does it's thing, it wouldn't surprise me if you were blowing some internal limit (but it should at least complain)).

Comment: @msw I agree with the database suggestion, but the join is failing because of sort order (currently numeric, but join requires dictionary).

Comment: Just because I asked the question in my comment: `join` uses a simple, old-fashioned external (tape) merge algorithm. There are no limits to exceed because at most a couple of lines from each file are in core at once. This does explain why the files need to be sorted as it is like the merge phase of the better known mergesort. Now we both know.

Answer (score 4):

Your files are sorted numerically, but `join` expects  them to be sorted in dictionary order (1 < 10 < 2 < 200 < 3). Use `join <(sort FILE1) <(sort FILE2)`. But (as suggested in the comments) do consider using a database.